# thoughtbot / paperclip Gem installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, paperclip

Im not going to start by saying i'm a newbie etc. Jokes, been learning Rails for  nearly month using Lynda.com.  I use Mac, Mac OS X Lion 10.7.

I am trying to intall Paperclip Gem but i can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong.

I followed the instructions on https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Installation

I added this line to my config/environment.rb

```
config.gem 'paperclip', :source => 'http://rubygems.org'
```

and i then tried to run

```
rake gems:install
```

I get an error message:

```
(in /Users/fred/Ruby/food)
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
/Users/fred/Ruby/food/Rakefile:4:in `require'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**I then tried the following as an alternative when the above failed**

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip
```

I get the following error

```
-bash: script/plugin: No such file or directory
```

My question is how do install this gem? I have read a lot of other posts that say i should include `gem 'paperclip', "~> 2.3"` is this the same as what i did above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best to use bundler. Steps are

1. Install bundler: `gem install bundler`
2. Add to `Gemfile`: `config.gem 'paperclip'`
3. `cd` to where the `Gemfile` is and run: `bundle install`. This will install all the gems mentioned in the `Gemfile`

Ps. I assume that you are not using [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/). Also, you *may* need to prefix `sudo` to the command in step 1 above in case the command does not work for you due to a permission problem.